# Adding comments to pages

Tags: 7

Is it possible to add a the content type comments to a page? When I create a page and look to see what can be added into a panel comments are not available

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be confusing things which makes your question hard to answer.

Please note that comments are not a content type, but they are part of nodes, and thus can be appended to any content type. Comment's can't be used inside the [Panels module](https://drupal.org/project/panels) because they are part of a node (one is to import the whole node).

If you meant page rather then panel. Please make sure the comments module is enabled in modules. And then go to the 'basis page' content type and check the 'comment settings' tab (at the bottom) to see if comments are open.

Comment: Thank you for the response!   The first one you described is what I was asking. Can you add a whole node to a panel? I ran across another module  (panelizer) which I was going to explore.

Comment: You can add a node to a panel using the last option in the add content dialog. Yellow square icon. There you have to enter the nid (node id) which is in the url of the edit page.

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to edit my comment as it was a stupid question  :)

Comment: If it answered your question you can mark it solved with the green tick symbol on the left ;)